# Create transaction by cardano-node using payment address generated by cardano-addresses

Tags: cardano-address

I'm using Cardano-addresses https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses. I have a problem when try to make a transaction by using cardano-node using address generated by cardano-addresses.
So what I did is :

1. generate a root private key (**root.xsk)** from recovery phrase.
2. generate a payment verification key (addr.xvk)
3. generate a payment address from a payment key (payment.addr)

---

And the when I tried to make a transaction using that (payment.addr),
I don't know what signing key should I use to sign this transaction:

```
cardano-cli transaction sign         
--tx-body-file body.raw         
--testnet-magic 1097911063         
--signing-key-file  what_key_should_I_use          
--out-file signFile.signed
```

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

Great question! Fundamentally, you want to use cardano-wallet to replace the following script in cardano-cli.

```
cardano-cli address key-gen \
 --verification-key-file key.vkey \
 --signing-key-file pkey.skey
```

In this tutorial, I will show you how convert the keys from the wallet format into the cli format.

First, create your recovery phrase and then a private key from that phrase. You have probably already completed this step, but here is an example:

```
cardano-address recovery-phrase generate --size 15 > phrase.prv

cardano-address key from-recovery-phrase Shelley < phrase.prv > root.xsk
```

Just for safety, let's go ahead and create a child key from that root key. It is not necessary, but we should get into in the habits of good security practices.

```
cat root.xsk | cardano-address key child 1852H/1815H/0H/0/0 > key.xsk
```

We have created our root.xsk and then from it our key.xsk. We want to use key.xsk to sign transactions. However, if you try to put it directly into cardano-cli, you will get an error. Even if you were to put it into a JSON format, you still would not be able to use it. We have to convert it into a different format vis a vis the following:

```
cardano-cli key convert-cardano-address-key --shelley-payment-key --signing-key-file key.xsk --out-file key.skey
```

Now we have converted our key.xsk into a key.skey. Now we have to create a verification key:

```
cardano-cli key verification-key --signing-key-file key.skey --verification-key-file key.vkey
```

Excellent! Now we have a key.skey and a key.vkey. You know what to do! Go ahead and create an address...

```
cardano-cli address build --payment-verification-key-file key.vkey --out-file key.addr --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

...and then build the transaction.

```
cardano-cli transaction sign \
--tx-body-file body.raw \
--testnet-magic 1097911063 \
--signing-key-file key.skey \
--out-file signFile.signed
```

Boom! You should be done!

We went from our child key.xsk, which looks like

```
{
    "chain_code": "4bfecd01af45a1abde446ec69522867a309f927f61a26d286d2475369e888e46",
    "key_type": "private",
    "extended_key": "c024ea34b52056996acb2f8f7d74b78b610ed773fb4ff6b933e460714dd8455edf6ea0b09c190126d364e69df714aef5824c7630f7b70e42050149f98b704448"
}
```

to our key.skey, which looks like

```
{
    "type": "PaymentExtendedSigningKeyShelley_ed25519_bip32",
    "description": "",
    "cborHex": "5880c024ea34b52056996acb2f8f7d74b78b610ed773fb4ff6b933e460714dd8455edf6ea0b09c190126d364e69df714aef5824c7630f7b70e42050149f98b7044480782a02ee41c9d7455faf2df6f36edb0c9d0c2c31eaf9e2f10f255ead21f53074bfecd01af45a1abde446ec69522867a309f927f61a26d286d2475369e888e46"
}
```

## Sources

[A great reference produced by the Cardano Foundation](https://cardano-foundation.gitbook.io/stake-pool-course/stake-pool-guide/stake-pool-operations/building-and-signing-tx)

[The associated examples](https://cardano-foundation.gitbook.io/stake-pool-course/stake-pool-guide/stake-pool-operations/transactions)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you. Let me try to do it. I will give back the result asap

Answer (score 0):

How did you venerate your `addr.xvk`? What derivation path did you use?

You need to use the private payment key to that specific derivation path.

Comment: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses . I created addr.xvk from root.xsk as the README of this article